# How do I get the year from a date in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a VBA user form where there is a text-box(txt_Date) to input the date. I want to get the year from this date. I have tried,

```
sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = Format(txt_Date.Text, "yyyy")
```

and

```
sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = Year(txt_Date.Value)
```

For the date, 4-May-2022, I get the output 14-Jul-1905 in both the above cases. How do I get the correct year, 2022, in this case?

Comment: What is the format of the cell?  What is the value of `Year(txt_Date.Value)` if you put a break point in?

Comment: Your formatting for `sh.Range("G" & lr + 1)` is set to `Date`, change it to `General` and you'll see that `14-Jul-1905` simply is `2022`. The code is doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: My bad. The format of the cell shows custom, which gives me the year 2022 when I change it to general. So I changed all the cells to general and now it I get the year. Thanks a lot!!!